# How do I fuel my spaceship?

Tags: starbound

I'm stuck on a planet with no wood trees and no resources that are easy to exploit, and I want to get off of it as quickly as possible.  What do I need to do to get my spaceship enough fuel to go to another planet?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As of 1.0 stable, only the purple colored **Crystal Erchius** and **Liquid Erchius Fuel** (requires upgraded Matter Manipulator) found on the surface and in the caverns on Moons (requires Breathing EPP to visit) can be used to fuel your spaceship. Note that travelling between planets in the same system **does not** require fuel.

Liquid Erchius Fuel can also be bought from the Infinity Express store on the Outpost, but at 5 pixels per unit it is rather expensive and should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Yes, I did ask this question just to answer it, because the game doesn't bother to explain this to you if you're stuck on a planet without any wood.

Comment: that is fine [and even encouraged](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @ratchetfreak I know, just thought I'd hedge off questions about it first.  ;)

Comment: In the ships I've seen (Hylotl and Human) the fuel container has been on the same side of the door as the cockpit. The station before the door is Tech/3D-Printer

Comment: @Katustrawfic Might be misremembering the position then.  I'll edit this to prevent confusion.

Comment: I use wood, as it's MUCH easier to come by than coal.

Comment: @kipster That's fine, but the question is about a planet without wood.

Comment: @Coronus Still useful though.

Comment: Upvoted for the updated answer, two years after the original post. Good work.