# How do you get fuel

Tags: starbound

I have just started the game and I need to find fuel for my ship. Where can I get This, can it be crafted? Can it be obtained early in the game?

Comment: See this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144767/how-do-i-fuel-my-spaceship?rq=1

Comment: Normal Coal ore would suffice